# Show two dimensional array without commas in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put an array to textarea, one element in a line. But every element is an array too and I need to show it without commas. I only can show every row without commas

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

outputText = document.getElementById('outputField');
outputText.value = arr.join('\n');
```

```html
<textarea id="outputField" placeholder="output" readonly autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could join the inner arrays with space.

```js
var arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];

outputText = document.getElementById('outputField');
outputText.value = arr.map(a => a.join(' ')).join('\n');
```

```html
<textarea id="outputField" placeholder="output" readonly autocomplete="off" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Join inner arrays with space using `Array.prototype.map()` on the outer array:

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

outputText = document.getElementById('outputField');
outputText.value = arr.map(inner => inner.join(' ')).join('\n');
```

```html
<textarea id="outputField" placeholder="output" readonly autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and to `join` your sub-arrays with a single space :

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

outputText = document.getElementById('outputField');
arr.forEach(e => outputText.value += e.join(' ') + '\n');
```

```html
<textarea id="outputField" placeholder="output" readonly autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```